# how create document and library in liferay

Tags: liferay

Requirement: Adding Parent  folders, Child folders and Their files to Document and Library from Particular location.

Case-1:   If Folder is already exists then get that id and add file

( Here I am using 
`addFileEntry(repositoryId, folderId,sourceFileName, mimeType, title, description,  changeLog, is, size, serviceContext)` of `DLAppServiceUtil` class ).

Case-2:   If Folder is not exits  add folder then add file

(Here I am using for adding folder 
`addFolder()` method of `DLAppServiceUtil` class)

My case its gives slow performance. That is the problem.

Comment: It would help to see what gives slow performance - and some measurements what you see as the actual (slow) performance: E.g. how long does it take to create folders and documents.

Answer (score 3):

Which version of Liferay are you using?

The current trend is the following in 6.1+ (well, when it is correctly implemented, but you can build more or less on this with the new `DLApp` implementation):

1. Locate the parent folder id. Use the default from the `DLFolderConstancts` if you don't have any.
2. Assume the folder exists and try to get it.
3. It will throw you a `NoSuch***Exception` if not found. If this is the case, create the folder by hand

You could do something like this:

```
private Folder getOrCreateFolder(final ServiceContext serviceContext,
        final long userId, final Group group, String folderName)
        throws PortalException, SystemException {
    final long parentFolderId = DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID;
    final long repositoryId = group.getGroupId();

    try {
        final Folder prev = DLAppLocalServiceUtil.getFolder(
            repositoryId, parentFolderId, folderName);
        return prev;
    } catch (final NoSuchFolderException e) {
        final Folder newFolder = DLAppLocalServiceUtil.addFolder(userId,
            repositoryId, parentFolderId, folderName,
            "My cool new folder", serviceContext);
        return newFolder;
    }
}
```

The docs and stuff are absolutely leaky about why you call the `addFolder()` that way, take a look on the portal source. It's not that trivial but isn't that hard to get used to either.